# Probability Saw the ads buy the product

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A new marketing campaign for an existing product that currently has 5% of the market runs advertisements in newspapers. Based on circulation and previous survey information, the marketing company states that the probability an arbitrary person sees the ads is 0.6. During the newspaper ads campaign, the buyers of the product were asked if they’d seen the ads – 75% replied that they had. Assume that for those who did not see the ads, the probability of buying the product is still 0.05.Show that the probability that a person who saw the ads buys the product is 0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the probability that a person who sees the ad buys the product. Assuming that the marketing company is correct, the probability that a randomly chosen person buys the product is 
$$(0.4)(0.05)+(0.6)(p).$$
For $40\%$ of all people have not seen the ad, and they have probability $0.05$ of buying, while $60\%$ have seen the ad, and they have probability $p$ of buying.

Thus the probability that a person has seen the ad, **given** that she buys the product, is 
$$\frac{(0.6)(p)}{(0.4)(0.05)+(0.6)(p)}.$$
We are told this is $0.75$. So set the above expression equal to $0.75$, and solve for $p$. Or else, note that there is no more than $1$ solution. so plug in $0.1$ fpr $p$, and verify that we indeed get $0.75$.

Answer (score 0):

Use a $2\times2$ table: {number of people who saw the ads versus didn't} by {number of people who thereafter bought the product versus didn't}. Pretend there are, say, 10000 people. Put the numbers in, based on the information you're given. It should give you your answer.